# jQuery: Multiple File Upload without modifying current php form

Tags: javascript, jquery, content-management-system

We have a CMS that allows us to build a file upload form, but it only allows **one** file at a time.I cannot change this or edit the php.

I am wondering if there are any create solutions out there to use multiple file upload using `<input type="file" multiple="multiple" />`, gather each file from the `files` array, then post to my form that is already created?

Currently we don't have the ability to do any custom php work to accept real multiple uploads, as we have to keep everything within the CMS at this point.

Any creative solutions to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use HTML5 to handle this.

```
<input type="file" name="myfiles" multiple="multiple" />
```

**HTML5**: http://css.dzone.com/articles/working-html5s-multiple-file

If you want to handle this on older browsers, you'll need to use a Javascript solution. jQuery documents this process well.

**jQuery**: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Multiple_File_Upload_Magic

Then, on the PHP side:

```
<?php
    $files = $_FILES['myfiles'];

    foreach ($files as $file) { 
        echo $file['name'];
    }
?>
```

Comment: I think you missed the point. I know how to ask a user to select multiple files. But, as I said, I have to use our current file upload form that only takes 1 file, NOT an array of files. I cannot edit the php.